# loader image does not show on chrome with an ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-chrome

I have an ajax request which shows a loader image before ajax send and hide the loader image after ajax when request success. loader image shows perfectly on Firefox but not on chrome.

> My code is working on Firefox

my code is..

```
$.ajax({
  method: "GET",
  url: "test.php",
  beforeSend:function(){
    $(".loader-image").show();
  },
  success:function(data){
    $(".loader-image").hide();
    //here i write success code
  }

});
```

Comment: You are missing a comma in between the beforeSend value, and the success key. Other than that I'm not seeing a problem with this code in Chrome. http://jsfiddle.net/cjmemay/e6bsmhxh/

Comment: @ChristopherMeyers : i just posted a simplified from of my code in question , it was an adding mistaking in question and i have updated question. but still the issue remains.

Comment: issue was fixed by @Rameez Rami ' s answer.. but anyone know why it's happening in chrome only? is it a chrome or jquery bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i hope this helps

> I had the same issue and i really don't know how it's happening, but it can
>   be fixed using a small delay in code like follows.

### solution 1

```
$.ajax({
  method: "GET",
  url: "/",
  beforeSend:function(){
    $(".loader-image").show(1);
    // please note i have added a delay of 1 millisecond , which runs almost same as code with no delay.
  },
  success:function(data){
    $(".loader-image").hide();
    //here i write success code
  }

});
```

### solution 2

```
   $.ajax({
      method: "GET",
      url: "/",
      beforeSend:function(){

        setTimeout(function(){
           $(".loader-image").show();
        }, 1);
        // please note i have added a delay of 1 millisecond with js timeout function which runs almost same as code with no delay.
      },
      success:function(data){
        $(".loader-image").hide();
        //here i write success code
      }

    });
```

Comment: let me try your answer

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems ok. but I think may be the beforeSend callback is not getting executed. As an other solution, can you try the folowing code:

```
$(".loader-image").show();
$.ajax({
  method: "GET",
  url: "test.php",

  complete:function(data){
    $(".loader-image").hide();
  },
  success: function(){
    //write the success code here
  }

});
```

Comment: let me try with your solution

Comment: OK. Let me know if it helps.

Comment: OK. Can you check the initial css style that is getting applied to 'loader-image' class. Basically jquery show/hide works on display property. So check if through your css you are no overriding the inline style. Please inspect in dev console.